# Transforming the sorting problem into Dijkstra

Tags: shortest-path

To get a lower bound of nlogn I am taking the sorting algorithm, which is well known to have that, and transforming/adapting it to Dijkstra's single source shortest path problem.

I know you need to do create a graph based on the numeric values and that Dijkstra will traverse it in order, any help with the rest and how to evaluate it?
Thank you.

Comment: What are the resource constraints?

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? Your question is difficult to understand. Do you want to prove the minimal complexity of the shortest path problem, or do I completely misunderstand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is to reduce sorting (or element uniqueness) to the *single source shortest path* problem (rather than to Dijkstra's particular algorithm!) using an $o(n\log n)$ time reduction whose output has size $O(n)$. Then you will get a tight decision tree lower bound in the algebraic decision tree model for constant degree (Dijkstra's algorithm can be implemented using a linear algebraic decision tree).

Such a reduction is probably not known. See for example [D.W.'s question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/25920/lower-bounds-on-single-source-shortest-paths-in-directed-graphs) on cstheory.